# Edit project dependencies directly

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I wonder, where are the `deps` stored in my applications?

Do I have the chance to change them directly in my applications?

Answer (score 3):

As `matov` mentioned in his answer, the dependencies are stored in the `deps/` directory in the root of your project, and **though it is not recommended, you *can* edit them**.

This is okay when you quickly want to try out some changes in your dependencies, but after you do edit them, remember to recompile them (they are not autmatically recompiled):

```
mix deps.compile
```

---

**But once you refetch dependencies, your changes will be lost.** So, if you plan on keeping them, you can still edit the dependencies and go with one of these options:

1. Fork the repository on github, apply your changes there and point your `mix.exs` file to use that:

   ```ex
   {:some_dep, git: "https://github.com/org/some_dep.git", tag: "0.1"}
   ```
2. You can put them in a separate directory (outside your project) and give mix the path:

   ```ex
   {:some_dep, path: "path/to/some_dep"}
   ```
3. If it's not an [Elixir Application](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Application.html) (with configs, etc.) and just a bunch of helper modules, you can also directly just move the code to `lib/some_dep` in your source code and remove it from dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Your dependencies will be stored under a folder called `deps` which is located in your application directory. It's not advised to changed them there though, but you can certainly have a fork of them on Github and load them in via that way.